# Android CordovaActivity display confirmation dialog before exiting

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

We have developing a cross platform mobile application using cordova/html5. The android application starts with an activity extended from CordovaActivity. We want to display a conformation dialog before application exiting using taping on the device tap button. We have written the following code. But the activity is exiting without displaying the confirmation dialog. But if the activity is extends from Activity class, then the conformation dialog works fine.

```
public class MyActivity extends CordovaActivity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Display alert message when back button has been pressed
    Log.i("&&&&&&&&", "%%%%%%%%% onBackPressed *************");
    backButtonHandler();
    return;
}

public void backButtonHandler() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MyPortal.this);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Leave application?");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave the application?");
    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for not using javascript to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at your code in detail but why don't you implement this feature in js side?

You can register to "backbutton" event in your js, do your thing and call nav.app.exitApp() if needed.

Answer (score 0):

the best practice here would be to handle all such stuff on javascript side, however if you still want to implement the same in cordova plugin , change line

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MyPortal.this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        this.cordova.getActivity());
```

and it shall work .

I know my answer is way too late but may help out someone still in need.